# Проблема с интерфейсом среды VB 6.5

Tags: vb6, visual-basic

Окно среды существует отдельно от других окон: проекта, свойств, формы, кода.
При развороте на весь экран, занимает только верх экрана и содержит только меню и толбары.
При востановлении, размеры изменяются, но не более чем нужно для содержимого меню.
Удаление и повторная установка не востанавливают MDI-вид главного окна.
Подкажите как вернуть привычный вид.

Answer (score 1):

Большое спасибо Инструменты->Опции...->Дополнительно->Среда разработки SDI помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Снимите флажок options -> advanced -> SDI development environment